# get and set access to folder or file

Tags: c#, security

I need to disable access for current user to folder(file) and then enable it again. If I disable it - user can't open the folder, and if I enable it - he can open it.

But how to do it in C#? For example I want to disable access for me. How to do it?
As far as I know I need to use `DirectorySecurity` and `FileSecurity`.
But when I do like this

```
DirectorySecurity ds = new DirectoryInfo(textBox3.Text).GetAccessControl();
AuthorizationRuleCollection arc = ds.GetAccessRules(true, false, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
foreach (FileSystemAccessRule fsar in arc)
....
```

`arc` has always `count = 0`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your application is going to have to run in elevated permissions to get that information. UAC is almost certainly denying that information.

Comment: You do realize that if you remove yourself from the authorized persons, the application (which is started by you) can not later on change the rights, right? That would contradict the purpose of user rights...

Comment: I see. Well I meant `me` because I am the only user on PC. I can add another users. It is not a problem.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar not necessarily, at least on Windows if the user is the resource owner.  The owner of a Windows resource can always change the permissions, regardless of the ACL on the resource [(source)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961992.aspx).

Comment: @drf So you mean being the owner I can revoke access rights for myself and then later add them again? I doubt that, really...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Yes, that is correct; the owner can always change the ACL on a resource, even if access controls on the resource would ordinarily deny doing so.  To demonstrate: create a file, and then clear the permissions in Explorer (giving no one any access to the resource).  As the owner, you will still be able to change the permissions.